# Cannot permanently turn off my screen via command in Mate without locking my desktop

Tags: suspend, display, power-management, mate

Sadly, I have some very annoying issue with my display. I have looked for and tested various solutions but none of them worked properly.

When I run the command

```
sh -c "sleep 1.0; xset dpms force off"
```

to turn off my screen it shortly turns off but within a few seconds (for example 5 seconds, sometimes also nearly 60 seconds) it will turn on again.

Something seems to wakeup my display.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with **Mate** desktop.

My requirement is that the screen does not get locked when the display gets turned off.

Here are some exemplary calls I have already tried:

```
sleep 1.0; xset dpms force suspend
sleep 1.0; xset dpms force off
```

Both commands result in the same behaviour.

`xset -q` shows:

[snip]

`DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On`

*Side notes:*

- The Unity and the Gnome desktops are installed as well.
- The same behaviour is given when the optical mouse is disconnected.
- No external monitor is attached.
- Even though I have configured in the Power Management Preferences the display being put to sleep when inactive for 30 minutes it sometimes will not turn off for hours.
- Usually, when the display is locked, it will turn off.
- I have a hybrid graphics card (the discrete card is Nvidia and the integrated chip is Intel). The discrete card is permanently in the state DynOff which means that the card is powered off and will only be turned on if needed. The integrated Intel chip is turned on and in use, so this device is connected to graphics connectors.
- I use the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver.
- When I switch to the Unity desktop this problem does not appear.
- My notebook is a Lenovo Thinkpad W520.

Comment: @Wiking `xset -q` shows:
`[snip]
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On`

Comment: @Wiking Running `echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state` turns my notebook into suspend mode, without locking my screen.

Comment: After reactivating my notebook, it just outputs "mem".

Comment: @Wiking Yes, it switches my laptop to sleep state. I have hybrid graphics with a Nvidia graphics card and the integrated Intel graphics chip (I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W520). I have enabled the hybrid mode in the BIOS, but I only use the integrated Intel GPU, so the other one is turned off.

Comment: @Wiking `ubuntu-drivers list` returns `nvidia-384
nvidia-340
nvidia-304
`.

Comment: This command returns  `Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau` And calling `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` shows `0:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0` which means, that the discrete (DIS) graphics card (= Nvidia) is turned off (and only gets turned on if requested) and the integrated (IGD) chip (= Intel) is powered and in use (So this device is connected to graphics connectors.).

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I'm having a similar problem with 18.04 MATE.  Did you ever find a solution?